# Finding the minimum of concurrent counters

Tags: c++, concurrency, thread-safety

I have several counters that keep increasing (never decreasing) by concurrent threads. Each thread is responsible of one counter. Occasionally, one of the threads would need to find the minimum of all counters. I do this with a simple iteration over all counters and select the minimum. I need to ensure that this minimum is no greater than any of the counters. Currently, I don't use any concurrency mechanisms. Is there any chance that I get a wrong answer (i.e., end up with a minimum that is greater than one of the counters). The code works most of the time, but occasionally (less than 0.1% of the time), it breaks by finding a minimum that is larger than one of the counters. I use a C++ code, and the code looks like this.

```
unsigned long int counters[NUM_COUNTERS];
void* WorkerThread(void* arg) {
  int i_counter = *((int*) arg);
  // DO some work
  counters[i_counter]++;
  occasionally {
    unsigned long int min = counters[i_counter];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTERS; i++) {
      if (counters[i] < min)
        min = counters[i];
    }
    // The minimum is now stored in min
  }
}
```

Update:
After employing the fix suggested by @JerryCoffin, the code looks like this

```
unsigned long int counters[NUM_COUNTERS];
void* WorkerThread(void* arg) {
  int i_counter = *((int*) arg);
  // DO some work
  counters[i_counter]++;
  occasionally {
    unsigned long int min = counters[i_counter];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTERS; i++) {
      unsigned long int counter_i = counters[i];
      if (counter_i < min)
        min = counter_i;
    }
    // The minimum is now stored in min
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Is there any chance that I get a wrong answer"* Yes.  *"I don't use any concurrency mechanisms"*  That's why.

Comment: Following @JerryCoffin solution, the code is fixed as below
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTERS; i++) {
  unsigned long int counter_i = counters[i];
  if (counter_i < min)
    min = counter_i;
}

Comment: Side comment on: "but occasionally (less than 0.1% of the time)": For something to fail 0.1% time, it has to be tested at least 1000 times :-) I presume we have a automated testing, recording, and comparison mechanism here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's broken -- it has a race condition.

In other words, when you pick out the smallest value, it's undoubtedly smaller than any other you look at -- but if the other thread increments it after you do the comparison, it could end up larger than some other counter by the time you try to use it.

```
 if (counters[i] < min)
        // could change between the comparison above and the assignment below
        min = counters[i];
```

The relatively short interval between comparing and saving the value explains why the answer you're getting is right *most* of the time -- it'll only go wrong if there's a context switch immediately after the comparison, *and* the other thread increments that counter often enough before control switches back that it's no longer the smallest counter by the time it gets saved.

Comment: to fix you should only have to take a copy of the counters before doing the comparison.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: It depends on what you want -- that'll give you the result that was correct when you *started* looking, but may be wrong by the time you finish (but it's still definitely a valid approach).

Comment: yeah, but min is going to be potentially wrong any moment after you assign min anyways

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is the problem I have. @JerryCoffin, you mean that the answer will be out-dated. This is not a problem as far as the result I get is no greater than any of the counters.

Comment: @user818100 There's also a race on the variable itself, it needs to either be atomic or protected with a lock.

Comment: @user818100: The problem is that as soon as its out-dated, it's possible that it will be larger than any of the others. Under the circumstances, when you choose a counter, its associated thread must be blocked from incrementing that counter until after you use it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, that's true if counters can decrease. But since all counters are only incremented, a changed counter can never get below the found value. Am I right?

Comment: @aseldawy: That much is true -- but the found counter can *increase* to larger than one of the others after you find it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Please check the updated code above. I assume this should always produce a correct, possibly out-dated, answer. In other words, the result (min) is always no greater than any of the counters, given that counters are only incremented.

Comment: @aseldawy: It might help, but then again, it might not -- the compiler might remove what would normally be an extraneous assignment (and, as GManNickG already pointed out, unless your variable types are atomic, the whole thing could fall apart anyway).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: That's right. I'm only using atomic variables for counters. This way I can avoid using mutexes and relieve myself from the overhead of locking/unlocking. I don't have enough details about compiler optimizations but I'll assume for now that it will not remove that local variable.